# Install a hardened glass in front of chimney

Tags: walls, screws, chimney, hole, glass

There is a chimney like this:

[image: chimney]

I have ordered a hardened glass with four holes to be installed in front of chimney with dimensions like this:

[image: dimensions]

There is a 2 cm empty space below glass to allow fresh air in.

I designed the dimensions in a way that the four glass holes would be between the bricks.

The problem is I'm not sure what's **the best approach to attach the glass to wall through the holes**. I prefer the glass to be **easily removed and put back** in place. Any idea is welcome.

The North-East glass hole is like this:

[image: North East glass hole]

Comment: I think you'll need to use a rubber eyelet. It'll protect the glass from the masonry screws and give a bit of space between the glass the brick. Just need to find the right size.

Comment: @MicahMontoya Thanks for rubber eyelet suggestion, looks like a good idea =)

Comment: Hardened glass isn't a thing. Are you using tempered glass or ceramic glass? I'd be worried about this shattering if you're using tempered glass.

Comment: Be sure to allow for significant thermal expansion movement ; like large , soft rubber grommets.

Comment: @user3757614 I'm told by the glass guy that it's secure glass or security glass. I'm not sure about its technology though.

Comment: I don't like the sound of "security glass". That sounds like the kind with integrated layers of plastic, which would be bad for something placed in front of a fire. It might be a different type, but this is the kind of application where the technical properties of the glass matter. You really need to know the technology.

Comment: @user3757614 Thanks, I'd like to dig deeper on its technology ☺️

Comment: Purely opinion, but I find this design aesthetically displeasing.  Why not use a standard metal-framed fireplace glass door, or at least order a piece of glass which fits flush to the brick instead of in front of the brick?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Can you share some photos of those alternative designs.

Comment: You can find glass doors/screens at any fireplace store (or Amazon).   My 'custom' suggestion simply has the glass sheet width a couple mm narrower than the opening so it is slightly recessed; some sort of L-shape hooks mounted in the inner walls would hold it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is standard hardware for the job, from things like glass inserts in stair/deck railings and glass signage.

Try "glass standoff bolt" in a search engine. You'd put an anchor and stud (or screw, depending on the standoff design) into the masonry and attach that hardware to/with the stud/screw. Looks decent, easy to unscrew when needed.

Comment: The holes are around 8 mm in diameter. Do you think I'd have to use larger holes with glass standoff bolt?

Comment: I guess it depends on standoff bolt design!